# How to read a 403 response in JavaScript?

Tags: fetch-api

Need to read the error response returned by the 403 API.

Code:

```
export const ApiService = async (endpointUrl:string,method:string,data?:InputLoginProps,csrfTokenState?:any) => {
    let fetchResponse = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_LOCAL_URL}${endpointUrl}`, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "xsrf-token": csrfTokenState,
        },
        credentials: "include",
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    let parsedResponse = fetchResponse.json();
    console.log(parsedResponse)
    return parsedResponse

}
```

The above code reads data only for a successful response, but I also need to read a 403 API error.
I tried,

```
if(fetchResponse.status !== 200){
    console.log(fetchResponse.body) //logs <Promise> not data.
    return fetchResponse.body.error
    }
```

But the above code returns a `<Promise>` and not the actual data.

The 403 api data looks like,

```
{error:"user does not exist"}
```

Comment: that code is not using axios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchResponse.json()` returns a `Promise`, so you'll also need to `await` it:

```js
let parsedResponse = await fetchResponse.json()

if(fetchResponse.ok){
    console.log(parsedResponse)
    return parsedResponse
}else{
    throw new Error(parsedResponse.error)
}
```

Additionally, it's best practice to use `response.ok` instead of `response.status === 200` to include the other valid status codes (201-299), and throw errors when there's an API error.

Answer (score 1):

If your response is a json, u still need to use  `await fetchResponse.json()`

```
if(fetchResponse.status !== 200){
const body =  await fetchResponse.json()
console.log(body)
    return fetchResponse.body.error
    }
```